# Windows 10 user access rights - Allow updates but don't allow new installs

Tags: windows-10, user-accounts, uac

I am working with a Windows 10 network with all users/computers connected to AD. I want to remove admin rights of the local Windows users accounts and put everyone on limited access rights BUT, I don't want to hinder the users' ability to run product updates for any applications as they are pushed out. I only want to limit the installation of new software without going through the admin.

Updates are not limited to Windows Updates. I want to make sure the user can get browser (Firefox, Chrome) updates, Adobe updates, etc. I just don't want to allow the user to install new apps that are not approved such as Spotify or Steam as examples.

What is the easiest and best way to do this?

Comment: That is not possible. Only programs that bring on own update service like Chrome, Firefox and Adobe Acrobat can install updates without admin consent (because their update service already has admin permissions). BTW: Some apps don't need to be installed at all, they can just be executed or the installer does not require admin permissions and installs the program into the users home directory.

Comment: So I can't load a machine from an image with all the preset software I have, give the user limited rights and then have it work so that preinstalled software can handle its own updates?  What I am trying to do is limit people from installing new applications that are not part of the stock image without going through me to get it installed but I need the app updates to happen for that stuff that is installed.

Comment: If you pre-install certain software then you know what updates needed to be installed. You can remotely install and update software as a domain admin e.g. using a comand-line tool like https://chocolatey.org

Comment: By default it's possible to install Chrome and Firefox updates as a unprivileged user, unless, you are managing those applications with a group policy.  Steam nor Spotify require elevated permissions to update itself.